# Gluu - Shibboleth - OpenSAML No Such Method Error - Jar Version Mistmatch

Tags: java, maven, shibboleth, opensaml, gluu

I have a SAML IDP server that is configured by Gluu version 2.4.1. It combines Shibboleth with OpenSAML and other features. When I sign a request to it with X509 cert data, the IDP throws an unexpected exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.getCommonNames(X509Util.java:162) ~[xmltooling-1.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator.processSubjectDNCommonName(BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator.java:290) ~[xmltooling-1.4.5.jar:
na]
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator.processNameChecks(BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator.java:254) ~[xmltooling-1.4.5.jar:na]
```

The problem is obviously some jar version mismatch. **Anyone experience this before and know how to fix it**?

The most confusing thing, when I download xmltooling-1.4.5 and open X509Util.java, line 162 is:

`ASN1Sequence dnSequence = (ASN1Sequence) asn1Stream.readObject();`

It doesn't ask for ASN1Primitive. But the error says it does. Can anyone provide insight? Thanks.

https://download.dcache.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/opensaml/xmltooling/1.4.5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of Gluu, 2.4.2, seems to fix the problem.